# Proper deformation of body mesh?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, weight-painting, collision

I've modeled a body, rigged it and weight painted it. Now that I want to make poses with it I realize that I have a few problems. The main problem is that when two parts of the body clash together, one goes on the top of the other and doesn't stretch like a real body.

I was wondering if there is anything I can do to improve that?

What should I be looking for? Maybe colliders?

So far it's impossible to do poses.

Answer (score 1):

Standard skinning approaches (e.g. the armature modifier) do not support collision behavior.

Self collision handling can be a bit tricky and certainly computationally intensive.

In blender you have two real options:

1. using physics simulations (cloth or softbody) which are difficult to
   get right and slow to run (using a corrective smooth modifier after
   the simulation can help a bit with looks though). They also don't
   handle volume properly.
2. Manually creating corrective shapes for the intersecting poses (and potentially adding appropriate drivers if you are animating). This can be quite time consuming if you have a lot of poses you care about and want to drive everything for animation.